# Align Image inside cell to the right doesn't work

Tags: pdfsharp, migradoc

I need to align on the headers an image to the right. This is my code:

```
Section section = document.AddSection();
table = section.Headers.Primary.AddTable();

var column = table.AddColumn("5cm");
column.Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Left;

column = table.AddColumn("8cm");
column.Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Left;

column = table.AddColumn("4cm");
column.Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Right;

eRow.Cells[0].AddParagraph("Some text");
eRow.Cells[1].AddParagraph("Some text");

eRow.Cells[2].Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Right;

image = eRow.Cells[2].Elements.AddImage(imagePath);

image.LockAspectRatio = false;
image.Width = Unit.FromInch(0.16);
image.Height = Unit.FromInch(0.09);

image.RelativeVertical = RelativeVertical.Line;
image.RelativeHorizontal = RelativeHorizontal.Margin;
image.Top = ShapePosition.Top;
image.Left = ShapePosition.Right;
image.WrapFormat.Style = WrapStyle.Through;
```

But it's always to the left, any help please?

Comment: Where is `eRow` coming from? Maybe you do not even add the image to the header table. In your code snippet you do not add any rows to the table you create in the header.

Answer (score 10):

I know it is a bit late
But you have to wrap your image in a paragraph.
http://forum.pdfsharp.net/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=158

Something like (I use parts of your code)

```
Section section = document.AddSection();
table = section.Headers.Primary.AddTable();

var column = table.AddColumn("5cm");

//I assume eRow is just a row added to your table
var eRow = table.AddRow();
var paragraph = eRow.Cells[0].AddParagraph();

//set the alignment on the paragraph object
paragraph.Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Right;
paragraph.AddImage(imagePath);
```

I had the same problem at it worked with the code/link from above.

Comment: Why the downvote?
Please explain.
I did provide a solution which worked in my case.

Comment: The OP is no longer interested in answers to this question. They already wrote that adding a paragraph didn't help (probably a new error in their code). IMHO the question should be deleted, but the close queue is too long and this question does not get enough attention.

Answer (score 0):

The lines

```
image.RelativeVertical = RelativeVertical.Line;
image.RelativeHorizontal = RelativeHorizontal.Margin;
image.Top = ShapePosition.Top;
image.Left = ShapePosition.Right;
image.WrapFormat.Style = WrapStyle.Through;
```

logically take the image out of the cell. This creates an image that can appear anywhere on the page, not just inside the cell.

Maybe it works if you simply remove those five lines. Maybe it works if you add a `Paragraph` to the `Cell` and add the `Image` to the cell.

If you would have supplied an MCVE I would have tried if my suggestions work. But you only show a code snippet.

The line `image.LockAspectRatio = false;` is superfluous, but does no harm.

Comment: I remove the 5 lines, but still is not working, I tried as well adding a paragraph and then add it to the cell but I get an error that says that value has to be cloned....

Comment: Where is eRow coming from? You don't show the code that leads to the "cloned" error (there must be something wrong with your changes). See also: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I end up using another strategy because it didn't work for me. thanks

Answer (score -1):

It will work if you do like that:

```
row.Cells[1].AddParagraph().AddImage(fileName);
row.Cells[1].Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Right;
```